# How can I replace using Query by Example in Spring Data JDBC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc, query-by-example

In my view I send async request to controller with Json Data as following:

```json
{
   "filters":{
      "someField":"someValue",
      "someField":"someValue",
      "someField":null,
      "someField":null,
   }
}
```

But data can be different.
And I have Order Entity that has same fields, so I can convert It from Json to POJO

After that using JPA I can do following:

```java
Example<Order> orderExample = Example.of(orderFromJson);
orderRepository.findAll(orderExample);
```

But I use spring-data-jdbc which doesn't support it, What can replace it?

Answer (score 0):

For cases like this where no direct support is offered, the correct approach is to get a `JdbcTemplate` or `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` injected, and construct the required SQL from your filter information. You may make the method a [custom repository method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations).